# How to use services or factories in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and i am currently working on a dummy shopping website project for practice.
I am a little confused about how to link the app.js with the files present in other modules.

I am working on a login module which has its own LoginController and LoginService in their respective folders inside the loginmodule.

In the LoginService I have defined two properties i.e. isLogged and username. when the user is successfully logged in using the $http.post() method(through the user table in database) the values are changed to true and username respectively.

How can I make sure that the loginService is available throughout the website accross different modules so that the user remains logged in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/ : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/ : https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=angular+how+to+use+factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make each section into its own module. You can use one module for your entire application. So instead of call `angular.module('newModuleName', [])` for each item, you would call `angular.module('app')` (without the []), and it would continue adding new components onto your single application.

The other option is to create new modules like `angular.module('loginModule', [])`, and then you add it as a dependency into your app, like `angular.module('app', ['loginModule'])`. From this point, any service/factory in your `loginModule` app will now be available for $injection within your `app`.

But generally, you may want to refrain from making separate modules for each section, unless that module acts like a "plugin" that is completely distinct and separate from the rest (ie. doesn't depend on anything within `app` to function). If you need two-way dependency, like `app` needs to make calls to `login`, but `login` needs to also make calls to `app`, it should all be within the same application.

You should also look at OAuth2 authentication and JSON Web Tokens (JWT) for the correct way to do authorization within AngularJS.

Comment: so does that mean I will have to call the app.js(main file) on each html page

Comment: The idea is to make a single-page application. And then you the html pages are the ones that change on demand, but the ng-app wrapper always remains constant. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute